# I can't render my website with Home "router" as a default page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a website that uses react router dom.The routes work properly but I can't set Home router as the main page, when I download the website, the main page is an empty background. I have checked that the Home router is the first and apparently the path is correct: "/". Can somebody help me to find the problem? Thanks a lot.

App.js

```
import { Home } from "./components/pages/home/home.js";
import { Nav } from "./components/pages/navbar/navBar.js";
import { Reviews } from "./components/pages/review.js";
import { About } from "./components/pages/aboutUs";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/aboutUs" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/review" element={<Reviews />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./home.css";
import Carousel from "../../../components/carrousel/carousel";

export function Home() {
  const slides = [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DCOICaqQoEY/maxresdefault.jpg",
    "https://unfilteredgamer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/terraforming-mars-ares-expedition-review-header.jpg",
    "https://gamecows.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Ark-Nova-Board-Game-Featured.jpg",
  ];
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="home">
        <div className="home-inner">
          <Carousel slides={slides} />
        </div>
        <div className="quotes">
          <img
            src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1889966854.5963/poster,504x498,f8f8f8-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg"
            alt="gamer-quote-1"
          ></img>
          <img
            src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.967398882.3526/st,small,507x507-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg"
            alt="gamer-quote-2"
          ></img>
          <img
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8_bOcNKvjb-NyMlFwqxOkfCPieb1CJcLImN1CsyPqtLXrk7lTn1BG_fUTso1W-SCoblo&usqp=CAU"
            alt="gamer-quote-3"
          ></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NavBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./navBar.css";

export const Nav = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setShowMenu(!showMenu);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <button className="navbar-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu}>
        <i className="bi bi-menu-button-fill"></i>
        {showMenu && (
          <div className="navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/review">
                  Review
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/aboutUs">
                  About Us
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Comment: What does "set Home router as the main page" mean here? Can you clarify? Can you also clarify what you mean by "download the website"? I see no overt issue with the code snippet you've shared. In RRDv6 the route order doesn't matter, routes are always exactly matched by path. It's not clear what any issue is from the code example.

Comment: Does using `exact` on the home route solve it? e.g. `<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />`

Comment: Sure, I want "Home" router" to be seen as a default page. When I download the website I want Home route to be seen directly. Now I can see it when I click the link on the navigation bar only and the first thing I see when I download the website is the page background with nothing in it .

Comment: Why are you downloading the website? That doesn't make any sense. `Home` is already rendered on `"/"`, so it's the route/component that should be matched and rendered "by default". How are you running this React app? Are you deploying out to a server/host and *that's* where you have an issue?

Comment: @MrCode RRDv6 `Route` components don't have any `exact` prop. In fact, RRDv6 routes are *always* exactly matched.

Comment: Is not working with "exact". Sorry., is not  download the website, I mean, when I visit the website. It should be rendered as default but only is rendered when I click the link

Comment: Can you [edit] to include details for where & how you are deploying the React app? Can you also include a more complete [mcve] that includes the links you are using?

Comment: I have edit the code. I use npm build and then directly npm start. I will  include also npm run deploy

Comment: So are you having the issue when running locally with `npm start`, or later after the app is deployed and served from a host? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: The same issue is in both cases. What I have seen is that the local host address is http://localhost:3000/board-game-website instead of http://localhost:3000,and when I take out "/board-game-website", the home route renders directly. That is the name of my website but I haven't made any route called "/board-game-website".

Answer (score 1):

I found it! the website wasn't redirecting well, so I include in App.js

```
 import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

I put in function App another  route path  that redirects to  "/home"

```
   <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
```

And it works perfect

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your app from a sub-directory on the hosting service/server, e.g. `"http://host-domain.com/board-game-website"` then you could likely benefit from specifying a `basename` prop on the router so that all routes and links function ***relative*** from this path.

See [Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router)

> The `<Router basename>` prop may be used to make all routes and links
> in your app relative to a "base" portion of the URL pathname that they
> all share. This is useful when rendering only a portion of a larger
> app with React Router or when your app has multiple entry points.
> Basenames are not case-sensitive.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <BrowserRouter basename="/board-game-website">
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/aboutUs" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/review" element={<Reviews />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Note that this fixes when the app is running from the deployment host/server, but will now have odd behavior when running locally. You can do two things:

1. Update the `homepage` entry in the package.json file to include the basename

   ```json
   ...
   "homepage": "./board-game-website",
   ...
   ```
2. Ensure you navigate to the basename locally if this doesn't automagically occur.

   `"http://localhost:3000/board-game-website"`

You'll likely want to also keep the "catch-all" route around to bounce users to the app's home page for any other routes the app doesn't explicitly handle.